# Deletion "Are you sure... ?" message shouldn't display the objects not declared in the admin

Tags: django-admin

I've the following case:

```
# class with an admin GUI
Class A(models.Model):
   B_set = models.ManyToManyField('B', null=True, blank=True, through="AlinksB")

# class with an admin GUI
Class B(models.Model):
   ...

# internal m2m class with an additional order that could only appear in inlines, not in a dedicated GUI
Class AlinksB(models.Model):
   additional_attribute = ...
```

When I delete an item from the A relation through Django's GUI, I get a "Are you sure ?" message that displays:

- A relaltion verbose name: the unicode of A
- AlinksB relation verbose name: the unicodes of any AlinksB related to the A object i'm deleting

But AlinksB has no admin GUI declared so I would like it to be invisible at deletion (since the user doesn't know what is it !). Somebody has an idea to help me please ?

Cheers

Comment: I figured an hasardous way: override Django's "django_admin.util.NestedObjects._nested(self, obj, seen, format_callback)" method so that when it is called with a format_callback is not None I check an additional attribute named "invisible" I added to some of my models as an attribute. But it is very hasardous if someday I change of Django version